# Too Many Cron Jobs giving me "bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable"

Tags: process, cron, osx-lion, sh, bin

I noticed today after some crons were not performing as they should that I was getting the following error line in the log files:

`/bin/sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable`

I did some research and found out it may have to do with the number of processes that a user is allowed to run.

I then run:

`top -u`

and indeed there are tons of `sh` and `curl` processes which I think shouldn't be there.

Most of the processes are simple calls to local `php` files running some DB maintenance tasks.

All the processes are running in my local machine, so I have full access to everything. If I knew how, I would change the limit, but I can't find any information related to this issue specifically on a Mac OS X Lion.

Also, I am not sure why the processes don't disappear after they are executed.

Is there any way to kill the process after it is executed?

Any hint in the right direction will be much appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only sane thing you could do is using lockfiles to guarantee that there is only one instance running for every particular cronjob. The simplest way to do this is by using lockfiles from within the cron-scripts. ("cooperative locking"):

- On startup, the (cron) job tests if the lockfile exists
- if the lockfile  happens to exist, the job performs a `kill -0 <pid>` on the other process (#1)
- if the errorcode from the kill is zero, the process  actually exists and is from the same userid. The new job should exit. (#2)
- if the errorcode from the kill is not zero, either the process does not exist anymore (good) or belongs to another (unrelated) process for a different uid
- if the process does not exist, the new job can continue by creating the lockfile, and writing its pid into it (#3)
- Now the actual payload can be executed
- finally the lockfile can be be removed.

#1: `kill -0` is a no-op; it only checks the validity of the pid

#2: there is a small chance that the pid belongs to an unrelated process for our pid. We can refine the search by inspecting the output of ps, and checking if the pid actually belongs to an older instance of our cron job.

#3: this is not race-free, but for a cronjob that runs once a minute it is probably good enough.

Comment: So basically what I can do is create a new cronjob which will kill other cronjobs processes? How do I know which PIDs to kill? Also, is there any way to remove the limit of simultaneous processes or its a physical issue? Thanks!

Comment: No, please read it again. Your cronjob shout check on startup if it is already running. Running the same cronjob multiple times make no sense. In the DBMS case, only the first will effectively run, the second and later will crab behind on their (db)locks. Or even worse: the whole thing will deadlock. (remember: the chance for a deadlock grows exponentially with the number of processes...)

Comment: Thanks, based on your answer I found the following post which seems to help http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2009/12/how-to-use-locks-in-php-cron-jobs-to-avoid-cron-overlaps/ . What I still can not understand is why when I run a cron similar to this `/usr/bin/curl --compressed 'URL'` the `curl` process will remain open forever although the actual process is completed. Shouldn't the process kill itself after being completed? Thanks again

Comment: @JordanBelf: Yes, any process should terminate when it finishes.  Chances are the process *didn't* complete for some reason.  You should try to find out why.  Try running it manually with whatever tracing you can apply.

Comment: And create a wrapper shell script. Change to the work directory, set some variables, do some logging, check the lock files, etc. All could be done in the wrapper script. BTW: maybe curl could not connect, and is retrying? proxy problems? Environment?

Comment: I keep experimenting this issue, do you know of any way I can find which PID represents which cron job? Right now I see maybe 100 sh and curl processes which I don't know why they are kept alive, maybe if I can understand which cron called them I can find the issue. Again, your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Cron jobs should cooperate. Make your cronjob (after safe startup) record its PID into a (well known) file. Let the second invocation of the cronjob fetch the file (if present) and retrieve the PID, and act appropiately . On exit, your cronjob should delete the PID file; such that the next one can continue. (this all presumes that there is only one invocation of every cronjob)

Comment: Thanks again! I will learn how to record the PID of my crons then, I have one more question regarding how the system works when its busy, as it looks this is the case. It just stacks the crons and then tries to complete them each time it completes a previous one, or if it is busy it just forgets about the cron? Thanks again and excuse my english

Comment: UPDATE: Got it working using the lockfiles! I have still to make some tests to see if all crons are actually running, but so far now my PID list is clean, no more repeated processes, and the free memory of the machine had tripled! :) THanks again